# OData WebApi: Custom action not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata, metadata, config

I am using ASP.Net WebApi that is enabled with OData (using ODataController).

I have a requirement to accomplish which I need to add a custom action but that not working, it looks I have missed something, can anybody let me know where I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!!

Below are code snippets of my implementation.

**Custom action**

```
[HttpGet]
[Queryable]
public IQueryable<User> PersonalInfo()
{
    int UserID = this.UserTicket.User_ID;
    return _users.Queryable().Where(d => d.UserID == UserID);
}
```

**Adding action in ODataConfig**

```
builder.EntitySet<User>(typeof(User).Name);
ActionConfiguration personalInfo = builder.Entity<User>().Collection.Action("PersonalInfo");
```

**Generated Metadata**

```
<FunctionImport Name="PersonalInfo" IsBindable="true" m:IsAlwaysBindable="true">
    <Parameter Name="bindingParameter" Type="Collection(Models.User)" Nullable="false"/>
</FunctionImport>
```

**EDIT 1**

I missed to mention, below is the error that I receive from expected url:

**No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://domain/odata/User/PersonalInfo'.**

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: Have you tried this URL instead `http://domain/odata/PersonalInfo`?

Comment: @DavidG gives 'The resource cannot be found'!!

Comment: @DavidG Though second custom POST action that I have in the same controller is working fine but don't know why this failing!!

Answer (score 2):

An OData Action is always uses the http verb POST and is typically for methods that have an effect on the server, however your controller method has the `HttpGet` attribute and it looks like you are trying to call this with a GET. Looking at what the method actually does (just retrieving some data) I think that you want to have an OData Function instead of an Action. To do this, just change your `Action` call to be a `Function` call like this:

```
FunctionConfiguration personalInfo = builder.Entity<User>().Collection.Function("PersonalInfo");
```

Comment: Function is missing in my OData library, is that latest?

Comment: Still not able to find Function keyword will you please let me know if that available in the latest library?

Comment: Which version of OData are you using?

Comment: I got that, thanks!, can you suggest how can I add multiple parameters to an action bound to a collection?

Comment: You have found the Action function? The ActionConfiguration class should have a method on it to add parameters

Comment: Yes, I found them!! previously I was doing this 'ActionConfiguration sync = builder.Entity<Contact>().Collection.Action("Sync")' but after update of the library previous implementation not supported anymore.

Comment: I have modified above code to use builder.EntityType, is that correct? also, this not supported any more: config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", model); config.EnableQuerySupport();, any idea?

Comment: From the original question, I think that you want a Function

Comment: @ANKIT: The likely reason why you do not find the Function keyword is, that you use a version of the OData Nuget package that supports OData only up to version 3.0. These are from before the time when OASIS took over OData standardization. They support only OData actions but not OData functions. You have to switch to OData v4.0 to get functions support: Use the package Microsoft.AspNet.OData instead of Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.